# Simulated location transmitted on Real iOS Device

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I simulated geo location on iOS simulator. Now this simulated location somehow transmitted to the real device. In the scheme configuration I removed a checkbox "Allow location simulation", but the problem still exists. Now, in all programs, even in the program "Find My iPhone" I see the simulated location, but not real. How do I fix this?
Thank you.

**Solved:**
iPhone reboot helps. How could I have guessed .. Thanks!

Comment: Run your app on your device using the Xcode debugger, and then turnoff location simulation from the debug menu,  if this doesn't reset location, turn your device off and on again

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature that real iOS devices can simulate their location, here is an [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html) for it, as well as a screenshot that should fix your issue:

[image]